# Webpack 4 Load Library Sourcemap

Tags: typescript, webpack, source-maps, webpack-4

I have a library `MyLib` that I am loading inside `MyApp`. Both are compiled with webpack 4 and `MyApp` uses `source-map-loader` to load the source maps for `MyLib`. As of webpack 4 the sourcemaps point to a minified file instead of the original source code.

Debugging into `MyLib` now simply skips to the following source instead of the actual code:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) { ... }
```

This used to work with webpack 2. What changed—or rather what do I need to change to get this to work again?

**MyLib Webpack Config**

```
{
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'my-library.js',
        library: 'my-library',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
        globalObject: 'this'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ]
    },  
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                        options: { configFileName: helpers.root('tsconfig.json') }
                    },
                ],
            }
        ]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJSPlugin({
                sourceMap: true
            })
        ]
    },
};
```

**MyApp Webpack Config**

```
...
{
    test: /\.(js|js\.map|map)$/,
    use: ['source-map-loader'],
    include: [
        helpers.root('node_modules', 'my-lib')
    ],
    enforce: 'pre'
},
...
```

**EDIT**

I added a repo that contains two folders `library` and `user` to demonstrate the problem. Use the `init.sh` script to install and link dependencies, place a breakpoint in `user/src/main.ts` and use Visual Code to run.

Comment: Webpack `4.01` had an issue with sourceMap generation and minification. Which Webpack version are you using?

Comment: Running webpack v4.15.0 and webpack-cli v3.0.8

Comment: @sqwk Can you create a little repo which reproduces your issue?

Comment: @Legends Added a repo here: https://github.com/sqwk/webpack-library-test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is related two two things:

- The library was configured as `SomeLibrary` in `output.library` instead of `some-library`. The name needs to match the name of the npm module (the folder name of the dependency in node_modules).
- When in development mode the sourcemap option of the using package was `cheap-eval-source-map`, which ignores loaders and therefore also the `source-map-loader`. Changing this to `eval-source-map` includes it.

Answer (score 4):

Since webpack v4 supports the new `mode` and `devtool` config, you can clean up your config files by removing many third-party plugins because they now come with `webpack` v4:

Try

1) removing the `source-map-loader` plugin

2) remove the following from config as well

```
new UglifyJSPlugin({
  sourceMap: true
})
```

Instead, just use the `webpack` built in `mode` and `devtool` config in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? "development" : "production",
  devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? "inline-source-map" : "source-map"
  // ...
};
```

Comment: `mode` is set through the npm script. I removed the `UglifyJSPlugin` and let `mode` handle that part, but unfortunately, no change. Also, tried removing the source-map loader without any effect. (Also seems very counterintuitive, as I want to load a sourcemap for the library inside the app.)

Comment: This saved me thank you very much.  Even if mode and dev-tool is set properly my source maps would not work.  I had to remove the SourceMapDevToolPlugin plugin from my webpack config as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need configure the mode that you are running,

```
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'source-map',
```